# Imbalanced Dataset - Binary Classification Python

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, precision-recall

I am trying to create a binary classification model for imbalance dataset using Random Forest - 0- 84K, 1- 16K. I have tried using class_weights = 'balanced', class_weights = {0:1, 1:5}, downsampling and oversampling  but none of these seem to work. My metrics are usually in the below range:

```
Accuracy =      66%
Precision =     23%
Recall =        44%
```

I would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks

Comment: What is the specific programming question? If your question is about statistics, you should post it on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of ways to improve classifier behavior.  If you think your data are balanced (or rather, your weight method balances them enough), then consider expanding your forest, either with deeper trees or more numerous trees.

Try other methods like SVM, or ANN, and see how they compare.

Comment: I tried using SVM but it takes very long time to run. Any suggestions on how I can improve it? Below is the code
from sklearn.preprocessing import Scaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
scaler = Scaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
C_range = 10. ** np.arange(-3, 8)
gamma_range = 10. ** np.arange(-5, 4)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(y=Y, k=5), class_weight = 'balanced')
grid.fit(X, Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try Stratified sampling for the dataset so that you can get the constant ration being taken in account for both the test and the training dataset. And then use the class weight balanced which you have already used. If you want the accuraccy improved there are tons other ways.

1) First be sure that the dataset being provided is accurate or verified.

2) You can increase the accuracy by playing with threshold of the probability (if in binary classification if its >0.7 confident then do a prediction else wise don't , the draw back in this approach would be NULL values or mostly being not predicting as algorithm is not confident enough, but for a business model its a good approach because people prefer less False Negatives in their model.

3) Use Stratified Sampling to equally divide the training and the testing dataset, so that constant ration is being divided. rather than train_test_splitting : stratified sampling will return you the indexes for training and testing . You can play with the (cross_validation : different iteration)

4) For the confusion matrix, have a look at the precision score per class and see which class is showing more( I believe if you apply threshold limitation it would solve the problem for this.

5) Try other classifiers , Logistic, SVM(linear or with other kernel) : LinearSVC or SVC , NaiveBayes. As per seen in most cases of Binary classification Logistc and SVC seems to be performing ahead of other algorithms. Although try these approach first.

6) Make sure to check the best parameters for the fitting such as choice of Hyper Parameters (using Gridsearch with couple of learning rates or different kernels or class weights or other parameters). If its textual classification are you applying CountVectorizer with TFIDF (and have you played with max_df and stop_words removal) ?

If you have tried these, then possibly be sure about the algorithm first.